# How to make allow slider to scroll to previous slides after Vanilla JavaScript has scroll past?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so this slider strolls well and works perfectly. Every slide perfectly snaps into place vertically  and horizontally on different screen sizes.  However, when the (vanilla) javascript begans to slide the slider to the next slide, I am no longer able to slide back to the previous slides until the javascript completes its cycle through all of the frames (divs). Each slide once displayed using JavaScript seems to disappear until it goes back to slide "zero" (the first slide). I noticed the scroll bar "thumb" on my version of the slider gets longer (indicating the entire slide package getting shorter each time the JavaScript displays a slide) each time the javascript "moves" the slides. So how can I alter my Vanilla JavaScript to only move the slides in my slider and not transform my slides where the slides are lost once viewed? My slides are lined up horizontally and once one is displayed, they disappear. Below is my basic HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Sorry I couldn't separate the Css and JavaScript I'm having technical difficulties.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>SGRLA - SA</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font/style.css"/>
 <script src=.3.3.1/jquery.min.js></script>
</head>
     <body>
    
    
    <div class=mainContentBoxSliders id=slider>   
        <div class="slides" id=ul><center>  
            <div class=sliderButtons id=sliderBtnsS>
              <a href="#" class="btn-prev"><</a>
              <a href="#slide-1" id="s1">1</a>
              <a href="#slide-2"id="s2">2</a>
            <a href="#slide-3" id="s3">3</a>
              <a href="#slide-4" id="s4">4</a>
            <a href="#slide-5" id="s5">5</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn-next">></a>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          </div></center> 
            
            <div class=slide  id=slide-1>
                <div class=imageWindow>
                <img src=images/photoOne~4.jpg width=100% height=auto>
                </div>
                <div class=mainTextContainer id=slide-text1>
                    My Text Content
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=slide  id=slide-2>
                <div class=imageWindow>
                <img src=images/photoOne~1.jpg width=100% height=auto>
                </div>
                <div class=mainTextContainer id=slide-text2>
                    My Text Content for Slide 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=slide  id=slide-3>
                <div class=imageWindow>
                <img src=images/photoOne~2.jpg width=100% height=auto>
                </div>
                <div class=mainTextContainer id=slide-text3>
                    My Text Content  for Slide 3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=slide  id=slide-4>
                <div class=imageWindow>
                <img src=images/photoOne~3.jpg width=100% height=auto>
                </div>
                <div class=mainTextContainer id=slide-text4>
                    My Text Content for Slide 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=slide  id=slide-5>
                <div class=imageWindow>
                <img src=images/photoOne~5.jpg width=100% height=auto>
                </div>
                <div class=mainTextContainer id=slide-text5>
                    My Text Content  for Slide 5
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </body>
 </html>
```

CSS

```
 

    <!----CSS & JavaScript------>
        
    <style>
        
    body {
          background-color:#000;
          margin:0px;
          font-family:'Open Sans';
          }
    .mainContentBoxSliders {
          background-color:#000;
          height:auto;
          width: 100%;
          
          }
    
    .imageWindow {
        width:512px;
          height:auto;
        }
    
    .mainTextContainer {
        padding-right:10px;
          height:506px;
        width:460px;
          font-size:20px;
          font-family:'Open Sans Light';
          font-weight:normal;
          margin-bottom:40px;
          margin-top:30px;
          margin-left:10px;
          }
    
    a {
          text-decoration:none;
          color:white;
          }
    
    /** On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) **/
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        .imageWindow {
        width:100%;
          height:auto;
        }
    
        .mainTextContainer {
          text-align:center;
        padding-right:10px;
          height:auto;
        width:100%;
          font-size:40px;
          font-family:'Open Sans Light';
          font-weight:normal;   
          }
    
      #slide-4 {
        background-size:auto 100%;
          background-position:center;
        }
    }
    
    
    .slider {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .slides {
      display: flex;
      margin:0px auto 0px auto;      
      width: 100%;
      max-width:1024px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      -ms-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      /*
      scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
      scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      */
    }
    
    .slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 3px;
    }
    .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #DDDDDD;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: transparent;
      
    }
    .slides > div {
      scroll-snap-align: start;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: 50px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #000;
      transform-origin: center center;
      transform: scale(1);
      transition: transform 0.5s;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; 
    }
    
    .sliderButtons {
      padding-top:60px;
      position: absolute;
      align-items: center;
        }
    .sliderButtons > a {
      z-index:12;
      display: inline-flex;
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 1.5rem;
      background: #5F6855;
      text-decoration: none;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
      position: relative;
      color:white;
      font-size:20px;
    }
    .slider > a:active {
      top: 1px;
    }
    .slider > a:focus {
      background: #000;
    }
    slider.img {
      -o-object-fit: cover; 
      object-fit: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #slide-text1{
        background-color:rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.275);/***transparent div background***/
        border-radius:15px;
    }
    
    #slide-1 {
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          justify-content:center;
          width: 100%;
          height:auto;
          max-width: 1024px;
          color:white;}
    #slide-2 {
        margin:0px auto 0px auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        max-width: 1024px;
        color:black;
        background-color:white;
        }
    #slide-3 {
        margin:0px auto 0px auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        max-width: 1024px;
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
        background-image:url(images/sarahSBG.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: auto 120%;
        font-size:20px;
            }
            #slide-4 {
        margin:0px auto 0px auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        max-width: 1024px;
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
        background-image:url(images/serahBg.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: auto 120%;
            }
            #slide-5 {
        margin:0px auto 0px auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        max-width: 1024px;
        color:white;
        background-color:black;   
        }
    .btn-next, .btn-prev {
    visibility: hidden; 
    }
```

```
JavaScript
```

```
     // Select all slides
        const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
        
        // loop through slides and set each slides translateX property to index * 100% 
        slides.forEach((slide, indx) => {
          
        });
        // current slide counter
        let curSlide = 0;
        // maximum number of slides
        let maxSlide = slides.length - 1;
        
        // select next slide button
        const nextSlide = document.querySelector(".btn-next");
        
        // add event listener and next slide functionality
        nextSlide.addEventListener("click", function () {
            
          // check if current slide is the last and reset current slide
          if (curSlide === maxSlide) {
            //alert ("next button clicked - Loading Slide "+slides.length);
            curSlide = 0;
          } else {
            curSlide++;
            //alert ("next button clicked - Loading Slide "+slides.length);
          }
        
        //   move slide by -100%
          slides.forEach((slide, indx) => {
            slide.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (0 - curSlide)}%)`;
          });
        });
         setInterval(function () {
          // check if current slide is the last and reset current slide
          if (curSlide === maxSlide) {
          //    alert ("next button clicked - Loading Slide "+slides.length);
            curSlide = 0;
          } else {
            curSlide++;
            //alert ("auto change Loading Slide "+slides.length);
          }
        
        //   move slide by -100%
          slides.forEach((slide, indx) => {
            slide.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (0 - curSlide)}%)`;
          });
            }, 6000);
```

Comment: You've got some errors in your HTML syntax, would you mind moving your example to the snippet editor (the button with the icon that looks like `<>` on the question editor) for a reproducible example. I didn't want to have to edit too much of your example.

Comment: I cannot edit the post anymore because I don't have access to my desktop right now and the interface here at stackflow keeps telling me that the < > feature don't support touchscreens.